# $\frac{\chi^2_n}{n}$ Stochastically increasing in $n$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I was wondering whether $\frac{\chi^2_n}{n}$ is stochastically increasing in $n$.

**My main problem**: Suppose $\hspace{5pt}\frac{(n-p)\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-p}$. Then the expected length of C.I. **increases** if one over-parametrizes the  linear model or, in other words,

if $n-p=k \uparrow$ $\Rightarrow$ $k[\frac{1}{u_k}-\frac{1}{v_k}] \downarrow$ where $P(u_k<\chi^2_k<v_k)=1-\alpha$

Of course, I was unable to show it. So I considered the simple case: $v_k=\infty$, in that case the above reduces to

$$k \uparrow \hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow \frac{k}{\chi^2_{k;\alpha}} \downarrow \hspace{5pt}\Rightarrow \frac{\chi^2_{k;\alpha}}{k} \uparrow$$

If $\frac{\chi^2_n}{n}$ is Stochastically increasing in $n$ then the above claim will be true, however it may not be mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n\sim \chi_n^2$. Asymptotically

$$P\left\{\frac{X_n}{n}\le x\right\}\to 1\{x\ge 1\}$$

as $n\to \infty$ because

$$\varphi_{X_n/n}(t)=\left(1-\frac{2it}{n}\right)^{-n/2}\to e^{it}$$

which is the c.f. of $\delta_1$. Thus $\left[\frac{u_n}{n},\frac{v_n}{n}\right]$ shrinks as $n\uparrow$. You may also note that since  $\frac{X_n}{n}\sim \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{2}{n}\right)$

$$P\left\{\left|\frac{X_n}{n}-1\right|\le \frac{2}{\alpha n}\right\}\ge1-\alpha$$

so that $\left(\frac{v_n}{n}-\frac{u_n}{n}\right)=O(n^{-1})$ (for large $n$, $X_n/n$ is roughly symmetric around 1).

Comment: I have 2 questions

(1) $\frac{v_n-u_n}{n}$ goes to zero but does that mean $n(\frac{1}{u_n}-\frac{1}{v_n})$ goes to zero?
(2) It's asymptotically true but can we conclude it's true for some finite $n_2>n_1$?

Comment: @Robert: (1) Let $\tilde u_n=u_n/n$ and $\tilde v_n=v_n/n$. As $n\to \infty$, $\tilde u_n, \tilde v_n\to 1$. Using Taylor expansion around $(1,1)$
$$\frac{1}{\tilde u_n}-\frac{1}{\tilde v_n}= (\tilde v_n-\tilde u_n)+O\left((\tilde v_n-1)^2+(\tilde u_n-1)^2\right)$$

So it should go to $0$ as well...

Comment: So just out of my curiosity is $\frac{\chi^2_n}{n}$ stochastically increasing in $n$?

Comment: Nope. $P\{X_n/n\le x\}\downarrow$ for small values of $x$ but $\uparrow$ for large $x$-s...